# Deferred does not resolve in Angular version 1.2.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred

When google is to slow, ask stackoverflow... For some reason I can't find something about this issue:

I read [this](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/) tutorial, which led me to [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/QBAB0usWXc96TnxqKhuA?p=info) plunk. For some reason `deferred`s didn't work in the project I just created using `yo generator-angular`, even after I copied the code directly from the plunk. Finally I found out, that I was using angular version **1.2.2**, while the plunk used **1.1.5**.

The real problem seems to be that `deferred.resolve` doesn't work as expected (not at all). You can see this behavior, after you switch the version in the plunk to 1.2.2. Strange enough the UI *is* being updated with 3(?) objects.

**EDIT:** I also found out that changing the controller to set the property **within** the promises `then()` function works fine. So version 1.2.2 simply doesn't allow do bind promises directly, like `$scope.message = HelloWorld.getMessages()`, anymore. Why is that? Also the interface of the promise changed, not have an `always` function anymore. Is this the cause?
I liked it better before *grml*.

Anybody can clarify this?

Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With version 1.2, your `getMessages()` method is a promise object, not the resolved data itself. Angular no longer automatically unwraps the promise object for you so you'll need to access the resolved data in a callback like this:

```
HelloWorld.getMessages().then(function(data){
  $scope.messages = data;
});
```

[Here is an updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5j1ARGtx6fX7zKw3ztaa?p=preview) illustrating the change described above. This breaking change [is described in more detail here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-rc3-ferocious-twitch-2013-10-14):

> **$parse**:
>
> - due to [5dc35b52](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577), $parse and templates in general will no longer
>     automatically unwrap promises. This feature has been deprecated and if
>     absolutely needed, it can be reenabled during transitional period via
>     `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)` api.
> - due to [b6a37d11](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b6a37d112b3e1478f4d14a5f82faabf700443748), feature
>     added in rc.2 that unwraps return values from functions if the values
>     are promises (if promise unwrapping is enabled - see previous point),
>     was reverted due to breaking a popular usage pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Anyway it's a bit sad. I liked the old syntax in the controller.